# Hive - create table - missing EOF at 'SORT' near ')'

Tags: sql, hive, cloudera, cdp, cloudera-cdp

I have this error when i try to execute the query (CREATE) below.
Any suggest?

ERROR: -------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
[sshexec] 2022-08-22 11:48:36: >> Query in errore:  
  [sshexec]  CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE OVCDX
  [sshexec]  (
  [sshexec]      `AAA...
  [sshexec] 2022-08-22 11:48:36:  Errore nel parsare la query:line 26:0 missing EOF at 'SORT' near ')'
```

---

QUERY: -------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE OVCDX
(
    `AAA`       STRING          COMMENT '<KEY>|XA',
    `BBB`       STRING          COMMENT '<KEY>|XB',
    `CCC`       STRING          COMMENT '<KEY>|XC',
    `DDD`       STRING          COMMENT '<KEY>|XD',
    `EEE`       STRING          COMMENT '<KEY>|XE',
    `FFF`       BIGINT          COMMENT 'XF'
)
PARTITIONED BY (
    `GGG`       STRING       COMMENT '<KEY>|XG',
    `HHH`       STRING       COMMENT '<KEY>|XH',
    `III`       STRING       COMMENT '<KEY>|XI',
    `JJJ`       STRING       COMMENT '<KEY>|XJ',
    `KKK`       STRING       COMMENT '<KEY>|XK',
    `LLL`       STRING       COMMENT '<KEY>|XL'
)
SORT BY (
    `AAA`,
    `BBB`,
    `CCC`,
    `DDD`,
    `EEE`                       
)
COMMENT 'X_ABCDE'
STORED AS PARQUET;
```

---

Thx,
Luca

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are using the correct syntax in your `CREATE` statement? According to the wiki, the `SORT BY` has to be used together with the `CLUSTERED BY`, in case it's in a `CREATE TABLE` statement:

[Hive Wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-CreateTableCreate/Drop/TruncateTable)

```
CREATE [TEMPORARY] [EXTERNAL] TABLE [IF NOT EXISTS] [db_name.]table_name    -- (Note: TEMPORARY available in Hive 0.14.0 and later)
  [(col_name data_type [column_constraint_specification] [COMMENT col_comment], ... [constraint_specification])]
  [COMMENT table_comment]
  [PARTITIONED BY (col_name data_type [COMMENT col_comment], ...)]
  [CLUSTERED BY (col_name, col_name, ...) [SORTED BY (col_name [ASC|DESC], ...)] INTO num_buckets BUCKETS]
  [SKEWED BY (col_name, col_name, ...)                  -- (Note: Available in Hive 0.10.0 and later)]
     ON ((col_value, col_value, ...), (col_value, col_value, ...), ...)
     [STORED AS DIRECTORIES]
```